# How to select an element having SELECT OPTION tags from Dropdown?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I am using WEBDRIVERIO framework. I have a dropdown in this html syntax. I tried to expand it using ID=question-3

After that I tried all the options using SELECT by options, values, text. But as it is obviously not SELECT DROPDOWN, none worked. I tried to click the locator based on the input or label option, but getting "element not visible" error message.

```
<div id="question-3" class="question ">
    <div class="single-dropdown">
        <input type="text" name="input-3" class="js-single-selection" placeholder="gender" data-question-id="3" data-index="3" readonly="" style="width: 77px;">
        <div class="single-select-container" style="display: none;">
    <div class="single-select-item" data-image="">
        <label for="option-0-3" data-open="exampleModal1" class="option-0-3-modal">man</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="option-0-3" data-answer-type="single" data-question-id="3" value="man" data-index="3">
    </div>

    <div class="single-select-item checked" data-image="">
        <label for="option-1-3" data-open="exampleModal1" class="option-1-3-modal">woman</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="option-1-3" data-answer-type="single" data-question-id="3" value="woman" data-index="3">
    </div>  
</div>
    </div>
.</div>
```

Comment: You need to click something to make the options to display out before you choose any one of them.

Comment: Provide the code you have used so far that has failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since html shows an input tag. I would suggest to :

```
 1. type the value in that input box (placeholder="gender")
 2. wait for options to appear (Label tag)
 3. click the appeared item.(Appeared label)
```

Also if your scenario fails please provide stack trace for the failure.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest clicking the Select Item (the input in this case), then implementing a wait (See docs: http://webdriver.io/api/utility/waitForVisible.html). And then clicking the dropdown item after you have waited for it to be visible on the screen. Like so...

```
browser.click(selectItem);
browser.waitForVisible(dropdownItem);
browser.click(dropdownItem);
```

Comment: Thanks @Taran. My failed code is exactly the same code as above and also instead of WaitForVisible, I tried browser.pause as well. But none worked. Its still complaining element not visible.

Comment: @Vinee these are things you need to list you've tried in the question it saves people time from suggesting things you've already tried, have you also tried waiting until element is clickable? and waiting until element is enabled?

Comment: @Vinee please link your entire code you've implemented thats failing, and everything you've tried in the question